# How to make an expect script to expect either of multiple texts

Tags: expect

Below is a sample snippet, normally it works fine unless we passes some command which shutdown the server or cause a disconnection .

To handle this, is it possible to expect either "#" or eof after sending the *cmd* .

```
  send "${_cmd_}\r"
     expect "#"
      send "exit\r"
```

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if the connection closes, expect will react to the special pattern `eof`. What you want to do is this

- if the connection is closed, expect `eof`
- if you see the prompt, send the `exit` command, then continue to wait for `eof`

```
send "$_cmd_\r"
expect {
    "#" {
        send "exit\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    eof
}
# do something after the connection is closed
```